# Heroku and MongoHQ: use Heroku plugin or separate MongoHQ account

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I would like to get the opinion of experienced users, If I going to use a heroku service as hosting service for my application that is using MongoDB. Is it good Idea to use MongoHQ integration, or maybe its better to use standalone MongoHQ account?

I'm excited about following questions:

1) Migration of DB from one app to another (Actully I couln't find guide of doing it for herkou MongoHQ plugin)
2) Migrating from Heroku integrated MongoHQ DB to usual MongoHQ account. (I don't see a way, expect DB exprot/import)
3) What about connection speed?

Finally
Why It is can be more responsible to use Heroku and MongoHQ integration, than using standalone MongHQ account.

And advise appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using the add-on and going with the integrated approach is simply to ease configuration headache. That being said, it is easy to switch from one to another by using something like `db.cloneDatabase()`.

The heroku addon essentially just sets some environment variables so don't sweat the decision too much, it's not a big deal if you need to move to a larger box (how long can it take to replicate 16/256mb)?

The problem with upgrading is that it isn't transparent like with the shard database solution but the nice part is that it is really easy to do manually.

Hopefully that answers your question, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thank you very much! Well, I will express my thought: I still have a doubt that heroku adds much over standalone use of MongoHQ service. What configuration headache? Setting up MongoHQ account, creating DB and user? If get I right the only useful thing that heroku does it and just adds MONGOHQ_URL. Well, not much. I can set up it manually, but I get more flexibility. And what If I want to use more then one DB in my application? Are there any other good things that heroku does for me in terms of potential reducing my time efforts? Or it just adds lack of flexibility?

Comment: Yeah, you are exactly right. It just sets the user, etc, up as convenience but I would set up your own if you are comfortable with it. I don't think it does anything special otherwise. Cheers.